# Recursion confusion with local variables

Tags: recursion

I'm trying to improve my recursion skill(reading a written recursion function) by looking at examples. However, I can easily get the logic of recursions without local variables. In below example, I can't understand how the `total` variables work. How should I think a recursive function to read and write by using local variables? I'm thinking it like stack go-hit-back. By the way, I wrote the example without variables. I tried to write just `countThrees(n / 10);` instead of `total = total + countThrees(n / 10);` but it doesn't work.

with `total` variable:

```
int countThrees(int n) {
  if (n == 0) { return 0; }
  int lastDigit = n % 10;
  int total = 0;
  total = total + countThrees(n / 10);
  if (lastDigit == 3) {
    total = total + 1;
  }
  return total;
}
```

simplified version

```
int countThrees(int x)
{
    if (x / 10 == 0) return 0;
    if (x % 10 == 3)
        return 1 + countThrees(x / 10);
    return countThrees(x / 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first condition should read:

```
if (x == 0) return 0;
```

Otherwise the single 3 would yield 0.

And in functional style the entire code reduces to:

```
return x == 0 ? 0
    : countThrees(x / 10) + (x % 10 == 3 ? 1 : 0);
```

---

***On the local variables:***

```
int countThrees(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Let an alter ego do the other digits:
    int total = countThrees(n / 10);

    // Do this digit:
    int lastDigit = n % 10;
    if (lastDigit == 3) {
        ++total;
    }
    return total;
}
```

The original code was a bit undecided, when or what to do, like adding to total after having it initialized with 0.

By declaring the variable at the first usage, things become more clear.

For instance the absolute laziness: first letting the recursive instances calculate the total of the other digits, and only then doing the last digit oneself.

Using a variable `lastDigit` with only one usage is not wrong; it explains what is happening: you inspect the last digit.

Preincrement operator `++x;` is `x += 1;` is `x = x + 1;`.

*One could have done it (recursive call and own work) the other way around, so it probably says something about the writer's psychological preferences*

The stack usage: yes `total` *before* the recursive call is an extra variable on the stack. Irrelevant for numbers. Also a smart compiler could see that `total` is a result.

On the usage of variables: they can be stateful, and hence are useful for turning recursion into iteration. For that *tail recursion* is easiest: the recursion happening last.

```
int countThrees(int n) {
    int total = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        int digit = n % 10;
        if (digit == 3) {
            ++total;
        }
        n /= 10; // Divide by 10
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: thanks your more simplification but can you enlighten me with local parameters? (i.e. total)

Answer (score 0):

In both case, you have to use a stack indeed, but when there are local variables, you need more space in the stack as you need to put every local variables inside. In all cases, the line number from where you jump in a new is also store.

So, in your second algorithme, if x = 13, the stack will store "line 4" in the first step, and "line 4; line 3" in the second one, in the third step you don't add anything to the stack because there is not new recursion call. At the end of this step, you read the stack (it's a First in, Last out stack) to know where you have to go and you remove "line 3" from the stack, and so.

In your first algorithme, the only difference is that you have to add the locale variable in the stack. So, at the end of the second step, it looks like "Total = 0, line 4; Total = 0, line 4".

I hope to be clear enough.